# What does "Il en va de..." mean in this context?

Tags: expressions

> Je suis bien responsable de tout ça. **Il en va de** mon devoir moral de vous prêter main-forte.

I assume that this sentence means something along the lines of:

> Je me sens obligé par mon devoir moral de vous prêter main-forte.

But I’m not sure how to interpret this construction.

Comment: Is it "Il en va de" that you would like to better understand ? If so IMO it would be appropriate to unbold "de mon devoir moral".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. The general meaning is that my moral duty obliges me to do something. The simplest sentence would be:

> Mon devoir moral est de vous prêter main-forte.

Other constructions are just more formal. Another sentence would be:

> Il **est de** mon devoir de vous prêter main-forte

*"Être de"* or *"en aller de"* both express the origin of the obligation, that is my moral duty. However, *"il en va de mon devoir moral"* suggests that there could be consequences should I fail to help you. Maybe *"my moral duty is at stake"* would carry the same possible negative consequences, i.e. what kind of person would I be if I do not help you.

Comment: Does the pronoun "en" mean anything in "il en va" ?

Answer (score 0):

Grevisse (*Bon Usage*, 14e ed. §231 c. 2°) caracterises the expression in a somewhat cryptic way, saying that, along with phrases like *il y va de* or *il en est de*, "the prepositional phrase is a complement like that in *au sujet de quelque chose*".

In any case, it's clear we are not in the same construction as cases such as *il suffit de* and extracted subject (*il n'en était parlé qu'avec le plus grand secret*; compare english *it was only spoke of most secretively*), but how exactly to analyze is left vague. I'm not sure that a parallel with the verbal form *s'en aller* "leave", where *en* has pretty much merged with the verbe (you can have an object with *de*, the same has lead to the word *envoler*) is appropriate.

I think for the most part these construction are best treated as fixed expressions ([TLFi doesn't discuss its history at all](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller)), as it is clear the *en* here is impossible to extract out.