# The meanings of "on aurait dit que" and "en aller de son honneur"

Tags: sens

> C'est là qu'il a décidé de m'aider. On aurait dit qu'il en allait de son honneur.

1. The phrase "on dirait que" means "it looks as if". Is "on aurait dit que" the past version of this, meaning "it looked as if"?
2. The part "en aller de son honneur" stumps me. Could you break down this expression? "It looked as if his honour ???"

Comment: There are two questions here: the first is a grammatical question (consitionnel présent vs conditionnel passé), the second is about the meaning of "en aller de son honneur". Please split in 2.

Comment: Luna, I've left you a message http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31973302#31973302

Comment: [related question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/20367/7321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meaning is : At that moment, he decided to help me. As if his own honour was at stake.

"**It looked as if**" is correct.
"Il y va de son honneur" **it's a question of honour for him**.

Comment: Welcome to French Language Armando. You  are not answering OP's question, you are merely translating their sentences into English. Answers must provide **explanations** (grammatical, lexical, etc.), translations might at times be added as support to an explanation  but asking for translations (and OP is not asking for a translation) is off topic on French Language and answering with mere translations is not appropriate. Please visit [the Help Centre](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) and we hope to see you around again.